# Using C Code in C++ Project

Tags: c++, c

I want to use this C code in my C++ project :
mysql.c :

```
/* Simple C program that connects to MySQL Database server*/
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {
   MYSQL *conn;
   MYSQL_RES *res;
   MYSQL_ROW row;

   char *server = "localhost";
   char *user = "root";
   char *password = "rebourne"; /* set me first */
   char *database = "mydb";

   conn = mysql_init(NULL);

   /* Connect to database */
   if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
         user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
   }

   /* send SQL query */
   if (mysql_query(conn, "show tables")) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
   }

   res = mysql_use_result(conn);

   /* output table name */
   printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
   while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
      printf("%s \n", row[0]);

   /* close connection */
   mysql_free_result(res);
   mysql_close(conn);
}
```

it compiles with gcc :

```
gcc -o output-file $(mysql_config --cflags) mysql.c $(mysql_config --libs)
```

but not with g++ ..

**What would you do ?**

edit :
The Error is : 
      exit(1); was not declared in this Scope

Comment: Please post the error messages you get with g++

Comment: exit() is declared in stdlib.h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first: it would probably be a lot more helpful if you showed us the compilation errors.

That being said, my initial instinct is to suggest:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <mysql.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
}
```

This is a guess right now, but without the actual error messages it's the best you're going to get.

Oh, and perhaps renaming the file to end in .cpp, .c++ or .C (uppercase) would help.

Comment: There is no need to do this. And people that use case-sensitive file names have  a special corner in hell reserved for them.

Comment: There is no need to do which?  The file renaming or the extern "C" declarations?

I know a lot of headers add #ifdefs around C++ to add extern "C" declarations internally, but I don't know if mysql.h is one of them or not.  Without the errors there's no way to tell.

Comment: Ah, never mind.  Just saw the edit.  Yes, with the actual error message it's much easier to find the error.  I'll put up a new answer explaining something here.

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
extern "C"
{
    YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, now that the answer is given there are a few lessons to learn.

First, *always provide the errors when you're reporting things that don't compile*.  Those messages contain valuable information.  Don't paraphrase them either.  Cut and paste them in their own code block.

Second, any time you use a function, **check the docs**.  I have never seen C documentation that didn't tell you the required header file up at the top of the man page or equivalent.  It's as much a part of the documentation as explaining what the function does.  There is a myriad of headers required in programming C and C++.  Documenting the required headers for functions is a very common documentation idiom as a result.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Though I doubt that it has really said "exit(1);". Please show *exact* messages next time.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I haven't programmed C in a long while (and was never at a very high level) but I find it odd that you would want to include a main() function into an already existing code base. Is it really the compiler, or the linker, that's complaining? And when you say that GCC succeeds in compiling the code, are you only compiling that one source file, or including it in a bigger code base as well?

If my guess is correct, it would make sense for you to rename the function to something other than main, e.g. connect_to_database().